# Analytics code preventing values entered in jsp to reflect in Struts 2 action class

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, analytics

I am in a serious problem. My JSP worked fine up till yesterday i.e. the values entered in the text fields reflected appropriately in the action class. However, for testing purposes I inserted an analytics code into the JSP.

However, after this, any value I entered in the text fields returned as a blank string in the back end. This has halted my progress completely. I do not know how this is happening. I debugged the application 10 times but with the same result.

Here is the analytics code I inserted:

```xml
<!-- Analytics code start-->    
<s:hidden id="uid" value="Step1"></s:hidden>
<s:if test="%{#session.cust != null}">
<s:hidden id="Type" value="%{#session.cust.Type}"/>
<s:hidden id="idCode" value="%{#session.cust.IDCode}"/>
</s:if>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/as/analytics.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://nexus.ensighten.com/gecrb/AO_dev/Bootstrap.js">
</script>
<!-- Analytics code end-->
```

Does anyone have a solution?

The problem persists even after removing the code, clearing the browser cache and cleaning the Eclipse project.

Comment: @RomanC: I guess test failed. :)

Comment: @RomanC : Analytics is something a friend came up with..it would be better if you ask him.. :)

Answer (score 0):

As you are no doubt aware, in struts2 Parameters Interceptor gets all parameters from and sets them on the value stack by calling ValueStack#setValue(String, Object), typically resulting in the values submitted in a form request being applied to an action in the value stack. (quoted from [S2 documentation](https://struts.apache.org/docs/parameters-interceptor.html))

Please check if any changes made to the interceptor stack, configuration of paramaters stack and if you are working in dev mode  [dev mode](https://struts.apache.org/docs/devmode.html)  you should get some relevant debug / error message.

Comment: I will check. Thanks. That makes sense. However, its unlikely that I have changed any interceptors. But still worth a try!

Comment: do publish how it turns out possibly add more information (your action class, jsp, struts.xml) so if it could be replicated